# Remove Nulls in specific Rows in Dataframe and combine rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need to do the below activity in Spark Dataframes using Scala.
Have tried doing some basic filters isNotNull conditions and others. But no luck.

Input

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|     Amber|     Green|       Red|
+----------+----------+----------+
|      null|      null|[AE,AA,CV]|
|      null|[AH,EE,CC]|      null|
|[DD,DE,QQ]|      null|      null|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|     Amber|     Green|       Red|
+----------+----------+----------+
|[DD,DE,QQ]|[AH,EE,CC]|[AE,AA,CV]|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input *dataframe* is limited to only

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|     Amber|     Green|       Red|
+----------+----------+----------+
|      null|      null|[AE,AA,CV]|
|      null|[AH,EE,CC]|      null|
|[DD,DE,QQ]|      null|      null|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Then doing the following should get you the desired final *dataframe*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(collect_list("Amber")(0).as("Amber"), collect_list("Green")(0).as("Green"), collect_list("Red")(0).as("Red")).show(false)
```

You should be getting

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|Amber       |Green       |Red         |
+------------+------------+------------+
|[DD, DE, QQ]|[AH, EE, CC]|[AE, AA, CV]|
+------------+------------+------------+
```

`collect_list` *inbuilt function* ignores the `null` values.